# EJB across applications lookup fails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I'm setting up two separate applications, a war with @EJB and an ear with @Stateless bean - they are seperate apps not modules of a mutual app. I try to get the war to work with the @EJB annotations, but I get an exception in runtime.

I don't use any descriptors yet, as I try to keep it as simple as possible.

Here's the war:

```
@EJB(lookup="java:global.myear.myejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.MyEjbImpl!pl.klarki.myejbclient.MyEjb" )
private MyEjb ejb;
```

Here's the exception I get:

```
    Caused By: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No unique bean of type [pl.klarki.myejbclient.MyEjb] is defined:
 No beans of type pl.klarki.myejbclient.MyEjb; owner=com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@22c86d85:
 display name [com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.PitchforkGenericApplicationContext@22c86d85]; startup date [Mon Feb 23 21:50:23 CET 2015]; parent: com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@43d7e0fc
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.getUniqueInstanceOfType(Jsr250Metadata.java:338)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.resolveByType(Jsr250Metadata.java:332)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.resolve(Jsr250Metadata.java:265)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.applyInjections(Jsr250Metadata.java:218)
        at com.oracle.pitchfork.inject.Jsr250Metadata.inject(Jsr250Metadata.java:209)
```

The below method works but it's not satisfactory, because I want to use annotation:

```
ejb = (MyEjb) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global.myear.myejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.MyEjbImpl!pl.klarki.myejbclient.MyEjb");
```

I can also make it to work when I specify mappedName in both the @EJB and @Stateless, but I've read that mappedName is not as cool here: http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/introduction-to-ejb-30-injection-and.html

I use mapped name like this:

in war:

```
@EJB(mappedName="someMappedName")
private MyEjb ejb;
```

in ear:

```
@Stateless(mappedName="someMappedName")
public class MyEjbImpl implements MyEjb {
```

Can you give me any advice what should I do to get it to work with @EJB(lookup)? Or maybe could you ensure me that mappedName is not as bad, and its ok to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The JNDI mapped name look stranger for me. Can you check, what is the mapped name server established for you EJB after deployment of the server side application? Try to change point after global to slash aka "java:global/server".